# Return PK (Situs ID) with NULL values for other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, left-join, inner-join

I would like to return the primary key ([Situs ID]), Account Number, and LoanPool even if there are NULL values for Exception Category, Exception Comments, Exception Code or Exception Description.

I was thinking to use a left join in combination with an inner join, but couldn't figure out where to put it.

```
SELECT        Questionnaire_Responses.LoanId AS [Situs ID], Loans.MainAccountNumber AS [Account Number], Loans.LoanPool, Exceptions.ExceptionCat AS [Exception Category],
                      Questionnaire_Responses.Comments AS [Exception Comments], Exceptions.Code AS [Exception Code], Exceptions.ExceptionText AS [Exception Description]
FROM            Questionnaire_Responses INNER JOIN
                     Exceptions ON Questionnaire_Responses.ExceptionId = Exceptions.Id INNER JOIN
                     Loans ON Questionnaire_Responses.LoanId = Loans.Id INNER JOIN
                     Questions ON Questionnaire_Responses.QuestionId = Questions.Id INNER JOIN
                     Questionnaires ON Questions.QuestionnaireId = Questionnaires.Id INNER JOIN
                     Loans_Questionnaires_Mapping ON Loans.Id = Loans_Questionnaires_Mapping.LoanId AND 
                     Questionnaires.Id = Loans_Questionnaires_Mapping.QuestionnaireId
WHERE        (Loans.Id IN (1,2,3,4)) AND (Questions.Active = 1) AND (Questionnaires.Active = 1) 
ORDER BY [Situs ID], [Exception Description], [Exception Code]
```

[image: Current Results]

[image: Desired Results]

Comment: Without sample data and desired results, your question does not make sense.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that I posted the code

Comment: You still can. See that edit button?

Comment: Thanks, I have added the code now.

Comment: Is that enough information?

Comment: I have added images for the current (1st image) and desired results (2nd image)

Answer (score 0):

```
May be you mean this (main changes marked with **):  
SELECT Questionnaire_Responses.LoanId AS [Situs ID]  
        ,Loans.MainAccountNumber AS [Account Number]  
        ,Loans.LoanPool  
        ,Exceptions.ExceptionCat AS [Exception Category]  
        ,Questionnaire_Responses.Comments AS [Exception Comments]  
        ,Exceptions.Code AS [Exception Code]  
        ,Exceptions.ExceptionText AS [Exception Description]  
    FROM Questionnaire_Responses  
    INNER JOIN Loans ON Questionnaire_Responses.LoanId = Loans.Id  
    **LEFT JOIN** Exceptions ON Questionnaire_Responses.ExceptionId = Exceptions.Id  
    **LEFT JOIN** Questions ON Questionnaire_Responses.QuestionId = Questions.Id  **AND Questions.Active = 1**  
    **LEFT JOIN** Questionnaires ON Questions.QuestionnaireId = Questionnaires.Id **AND Questionnaires.Active = 1**  
    **LEFT JOIN** Loans_Questionnaires_Mapping ON Loans.Id = Loans_Questionnaires_Mapping.LoanId  
        AND Questionnaires.Id = Loans_Questionnaires_Mapping.QuestionnaireId  
    WHERE  Loans.Id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)  
    ORDER BY [Situs ID]  
        ,[Exception Description]  
        ,[Exception Code];
```

Comment: Hi etsa, that brings through multiple rows where there is a Question (~122 for each Situs ID). However I only want to bring through one row per Situs ID if the Exception Category is NULL.

Comment: Please comment your solution, code only answers isn't allowed.